# Adding a prefix to hostnames with docker compose?

Tags: docker, docker-compose

I'm using docker compose to create a bunch of containers, and the internal hostname is the container ID; when each container registers its hostname in ... whatever (but consul in this instance) it's hard to tell the hosts apart.

In particular, when combined with `--scale`, I end up with something like the following:

```
09f62d66a050.docker_default
56f1dc03a54c.docker_default
772799d94048.docker_default
983c5cda71c7.docker_default
a7c77bb2dd98.docker_default
```

I can't just set `hostname` in `docker-compose.yml` (because I'm using `--scale`).

**How do I add a prefix to the generated hostname?**

I'm cool with my hosts being called `web-56f1dc03a54c`, `web-a7c77bb2dd98`, `redis-09f62d66a050`, etc.